# Sequence generation for Oracle and MYSQL with same code base with Hibernate persistence provider

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, hibernate

in my project we are using Oracle and we want to give support for MYSQL also. In POJOs/Domains we used sequence generator annotation. Oracle have sequence support but MYSQL don't have. How to handle with same code base? can any help me here out please.

NOTE: We dont want to change out existing code using IDENTITY annotation @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)

```
Ex:
Class POJO{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seqgenerator")
@SequenceGenerator(--,--,--)
------
-------
}
```

Comment: Mysql have autoincrement support...it doesn't need sequences...In Oracle 12c you have the identity constraint

Comment: Sequences are emulated in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

To support both oracle and mysql, use AUTO generated type As:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
```